# How to log a message when jshint task runs and everything is correct?

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint

I am working on a Gulp file and I am doing the task for jshint to check my code.

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['public/**/*.js', 
                     '!public/vendor/*.js', '!public/app.min.js', '!public/fonts/*.*',
                     '!public/favico.png', '!public/templates.js'])
            .pipe(jshint())
            .pipe(jshint.reporter( 'default' ));
});
```

I just fix some errors I had in the code but the console/terminal didn't print anything to know if now everything is correct.

How should I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [github project](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint) page,

you can create a custom reporter that will print every error.

code is like this:

```
  var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
    var map = require('map-stream');

    var myReporter = map(function (file, cb) {
      if (!file.jshint.success) {
        console.log('JSHINT fail in '+file.path);
        file.jshint.results.forEach(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(' '+file.path + ': line ' + err.line + ', col ' + err.character + ', code ' + err.code + ', ' + err.reason);
          }
        });
      }
      cb(null, file);
    });

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['public/**/*.js', 
                     '!public/vendor/*.js', '!public/app.min.js', '!public/fonts/*.*',
                     '!public/favico.png', '!public/templates.js'])
            .pipe(jshint())
           .pipe(myReporter);
});
```

Comment: So weird, I am getting Invalid Reporter message :/

Comment: Example is from doc page with some changes for your case.

Comment: Can you share the output?